# Customize Facebook friend picker?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I would like to customize Facebook friend picker? I am interested in changing the background color of the FBFriendPickerViewController's tableview. I am able to do it, but what my problem is I am not able to remove white background color of last name label of of Facebook friend.

Answer (score 1):

Use this method to change the `UITableView` `backgroundColor` and also change the cell color.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```